# Can I do this with a file .asp?

Tags: sql, .net, database, file

I would like to know if I could make a script with .aspx with which

I would make a query a database where I would have a name of a file and go to the path where the file is and I can modify the name or path

```
<script runat="server">    
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Prova1\mover1.txt", "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Prova1\mover2.txt")
    End Sub
</script>
```

I did that but how can i execute the script for cmd or powershell?

Comment: Stack Overflow uses ASP.NET, so obviously yes but you *shouldn't* put your code in the page. This is covered in every ASP.NET tutorial, whether it's for Web Forms, ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your Comment! Can you check again my question please?